# How do I reload cells in UICollectionView without reloading the header?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionreusableview

I am trying to update the content of the cells in a UICollectionView based on what the user inputs into a textField in the header. I have looked at other similar questions here but none of their answers have seemed to work.I even tried implementing an extension to the UICollectionView which goes through each cell in the section trying to reload its data but that leads to a crash as the number of cells are changing after the user enters into the textField

Function I attempted to solve the problem, I have only one section so I hard coded in that section

```
    @objc func textFieldDidChange(){
        guard(!(feedSearchBar.text?.isEmpty)!) else{
            VC.currentTagsArray = VC.genericTagsArray
            VC.feedScreenCollectionView.reloadData()
            return
        }
        VC.currentTagsArray = VC.genericTagsArray.filter({letter -> Bool in
            if feedSearchBar.text!.count > letter.count{
                return false
            }
            let stringRange = letter.index(letter.startIndex, offsetBy: feedSearchBar.text!.count)
            let subword = letter[..<stringRange]
            return subword.lowercased().contains(feedSearchBar.text!.lowercased())

        })

        if VC.currentTagsArray.isEmpty{
            VC.currentTagsArray.insert(feedSearchBar.text!, at: 0)
        }
    VC.feedScreenCollectionView.reloadItems(inSection: 0)
   }

extension UICollectionView{
    func reloadItems(inSection section:Int = 0) {
        print("made it to reload")
        for i in 0..<self.numberOfItems(inSection: section){
        self.reloadItems(at: [IndexPath(item: i, section: section)])
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code in its entirety from the project

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource,printDelegateWorkedDelegate,updateCollectionView{

    func updateCollectionView() {
        self.feedScreenCollectionView.reloadData()
    }

    func printDelegateWorkedDelegate() {
        print("The delegate worked")
    }

    var genericTagsArray:[String] = ["tag1","tag2","tag3","tag4","tag5","tag6","tag7","tag8","tag9","tag10","tag11","tag12","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","Ab","Abc","za","tag1","tag2","tag3","tag4","tag5","tag6","tag7","tag8","tag9","tag10","tag11","tag12","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","Ab","Abc","za"]
    var currentTagsArray:[String] = [String]()
    var tagsSelected:[String] = [String]()
    let keyboardSlider = KeyboardSlider()

    var header:feedViewHeader = feedViewHeader()

    @IBOutlet weak var feedScreenCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        keyboardSlider.subscribeToKeyboardNotifications(view: view)
        currentTagsArray = genericTagsArray

        let viewTapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(feedViewHeader.viewTapped(gestureRecognizer:)))
        viewTapGestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
        self.feedScreenCollectionView.addGestureRecognizer(viewTapGestureRecognizer)

        feedScreenCollectionView.delegate = self
        //
        feedScreenCollectionView.dataSource = self
        //

        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 5, left: 1, bottom: 0, right: 1)
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
        layout.headerReferenceSize = CGSize(width: 50, height: 75)

        layout.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true
        feedScreenCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
            return CGSize(width: 50, height: 75)
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
                header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "feedViewHeader", for: indexPath) as! feedViewHeader
            header.VC = self
        return header

    }
    //


    //Data Source
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return currentTagsArray.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "feedViewCell", for: indexPath) as! feedViewCell
        cell.feedImageView.backgroundColor = .blue
        cell.feedImageView.clipsToBounds = true
        cell.feedImageView.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat((cell.feedImageView.frame.width)/5)
        cell.feedLabel.text = currentTagsArray[indexPath.item]
        return cell
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat{
        return 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let collectionViewWidth = collectionView.bounds.width/4.0
        let collectionViewHeight = collectionViewWidth
        return CGSize(width: collectionViewWidth-4, height: collectionViewHeight+25)
    }
    var lastContentOffset:CGFloat = 0

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        if self.lastContentOffset > self.feedScreenCollectionView.contentOffset.y && self.feedScreenCollectionView.contentOffset.y > 0 && self.feedScreenCollectionView.contentOffset.y < self.feedScreenCollectionView.frame.maxY {
            self.lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
            header.isHidden = false
        }
        else if (self.lastContentOffset < self.feedScreenCollectionView.contentOffset.y) && (self.feedScreenCollectionView.contentOffset.y < self.feedScreenCollectionView.frame.maxY) && (self.feedScreenCollectionView.contentOffset.y > 0)  {
            print("you scrolled down,content offSet: \(scrollView.contentOffset.y)->\(self.feedScreenCollectionView.contentOffset.y)")
            header.isHidden = true
        }
        else{
            self.lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
            print("content offSet: \(scrollView.contentOffset.y)")
            print("Nothing happened")
            //  self.headerDelegate?.hideHeaderView(hide: true)
        }


    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.keyboardFrameChangeNotification(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame, object: nil)
    }

    var offsetY:CGFloat = 0

    @objc func keyboardFrameChangeNotification(notification: Notification) {
    }


}


class feedViewCell:UICollectionViewCell{

    @IBOutlet weak var feedImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var feedLabel: UILabel!

    let keyboardSlider = KeyboardSlider()

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        feedLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        feedImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor).isActive = true
        feedImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        feedImageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        feedImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.feedLabel.topAnchor).isActive = true

        feedImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        feedLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        feedLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        feedLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        feedLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.feedImageView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        feedLabel.textAlignment = .center

    }

}




class feedViewHeader:UICollectionReusableView,UITextFieldDelegate,UICollectionViewDelegate{

    @IBOutlet weak var feedSearchBar: UITextField!

    var delegateWorked:printDelegateWorkedDelegate?
    var updateCV:updateCollectionView?


    var VC:ViewController!
    var collectionView:UICollectionView?
    var stringToBeSet = "String to be set"

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        feedSearchBar.delegate = self
        feedSearchBar.autocorrectionType = .no
        feedSearchBar.keyboardType = .default
          feedSearchBar.addTarget(self, action: #selector(feedViewHeader.textFieldDidChange), for: .editingChanged)
        self.feedSearchBar.borderStyle = .roundedRect
        self.feedSearchBar.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        self.feedSearchBar.layer.borderWidth = 4
        var searchBarHeight = self.feedSearchBar.bounds.height
        self.feedSearchBar.placeholder = "Tap To Search"
        self.feedSearchBar.returnKeyType = .search
        self.feedSearchBar.rightViewMode = .always
    }


    @objc func viewTapped(gestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer){

        if  feedSearchBar.isFirstResponder{
            feedSearchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        }
    }

   func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
     VC.feedScreenCollectionView.reloadData()

    //VC.feedScreenCollectionView.reloadSections([0])
    return true
    }

    /// Helper to dismiss keyboard
    @objc func didStopEditing() {
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        UIView.setAnimationCurve(UIViewAnimationCurve.easeInOut)
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
            self.VC.view.frame.origin.y = 0
        }
    }
    @objc func textFieldDidChange(){
        guard(!(feedSearchBar.text?.isEmpty)!) else{
            VC.currentTagsArray = VC.genericTagsArray
            VC.feedScreenCollectionView.reloadData()
            return
        }

        VC.currentTagsArray = VC.genericTagsArray.filter({letter -> Bool in
           if feedSearchBar.text!.count > letter.count{
                return false
            }
            let stringRange = letter.index(letter.startIndex, offsetBy: feedSearchBar.text!.count)
            let subword = letter[..<stringRange]
            return subword.lowercased().contains(feedSearchBar.text!.lowercased())

        })

        if VC.currentTagsArray.isEmpty{
            VC.currentTagsArray.insert(feedSearchBar.text!, at: 0)
        }
    VC.feedScreenCollectionView.reloadItems(inSection: 0)
   }
}

extension Notification.Name{
    static let showKeyboard = Notification.Name("showKeyboard")
}
class KeyboardSlider: NSObject {
    // variables to hold and process information from the view using this class
    weak var view: UIView?

    @objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
        // method to move keyboard up
        // view?.frame.origin.y = 0 - getKeyboardHeight(notification as Notification)
        print("made it to keyboard will show")
    }

    func getKeyboardHeight(_ notification:Notification) -> CGFloat {
        // get exact height of keyboard on all devices and convert to float value to return for use
        let userInfo = notification.userInfo
        let keyboardSize = userInfo![UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue
        return keyboardSize.cgRectValue.height
    }

    func subscribeToKeyboardNotifications(view: UIView) {
        // assigning view to class' counterpart
        self.view = view
        // when UIKeyboardWillShow do keyboardWillShow function
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(notification:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    }

    func unsubscribeFromKeyboardNotifications() {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    }
}

class blankView:UICollectionReusableView{

}

extension UICollectionView{
    func reloadItems(inSection section:Int = 0) {
        print("made it to reload")
        for i in 0..<self.numberOfItems(inSection: section){
        self.reloadItems(at: [IndexPath(item: i, section: section)])
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the method

**Objective-C**

```
- (void)reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths
```

**Swift**

```
func reloadItems(at indexPaths: [IndexPath])
```

Where you can pass an array of indexPaths that you want to update.
More info in the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618055-reloaditemsatindexpaths)

Comment: Thank you for your response, I tried doing that in an extension to UICollectionView like so:                                                                                       func reloadItems(inSection section:Int = 0) {
        var indicies:[IndexPath] = [IndexPath]()
        for i in 0..<self.numberOfItems(inSection: section){
        indicies.append(IndexPath(item: i, section: section))
        }
        self.reloadItems(at: indicies)
    }   but the app crashes and I receive an error about not having the same number of items when I call the function from `textFieldDidChange`

Comment: The error says " *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert item 6 into section 0, but there are only 6 items in section 0 after the update'"